# How to modify an Android class inside a jar file without unpacking?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to modify a class inside a jar file, but since it's using hidden Android API's, I can't unpack it and then repack it after modifying it. I tried to copy the source to my app's folder, Then I removed all other classes, only keeping the intended class.

When I tried to build the app, I got this:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
```

I don't know a way to remove the class from the jar, also changing package and class name is not a solution because it introduces some type errors.

Is anybody aware of a way to remove a class from a jar file? Is there another way to change a class without unpacking the jar file?

Comment: [What are actually trying to achieve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose As I said, I want to change a class inside a third-party jar to change my application's behavior, without unpacking the jar file.